# Is it possible to let chrome devtools give different values of battery level and charging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging a javascript that i cannot modify and does different things according battery level and charging status on mobile devices. 
I work with latest chrome version on android phone connected to a PC using an USB cable and chrome developer tools on PC.
My problem is that with this configuration with a script like this:

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
    var level = battery.level;
    console.log(battery);
});
```

i always have `battery.charghing=true` and `battery.level=1`  while i need to see the script behaviour using a lower battery level and battery.charging=false. 
Is it possible to do it?
I cannot use debugger breakpoint because in that case the script has even different behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always hardcode your debug values or in this case create a complete copy of the original `battery`:

```js
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
  var level = battery.level;

  console.log("Original battery:", battery);

  //DEBUG START
  battery = {
    "charging": false,
    "chargingTime": 100,
    "dischargingTime": Infinity,
    "level": 42,
  };
  //DEBUG END

  console.log("Debug battery:", battery);
});
```

Comment: I tried to copy the element directly as well, but `Object.assign({},battery)` returns an empty object.

Comment: my problem is that the script is not mine. My problem is that there is somebody that is trying to do nasty things and this is a protection. I need to bypass this protection to see who is the owner of the page and give evidence that it's doing thing outside the agreements. 
I know the final owner of the service, but i also need to know which affiliate is using it.

Comment: so do you have any control over the js environment? Because then you can maybe overwrite the complete `navigator.getBattery()` method